# 'initializing': cannot convert from 'T []' to 'T []'

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, operator-keyword

```cpp
tarray<T> operator=(T para_arr[]) 
{
    T  f_arr[] = para_arr;
    return tarray<T>();
}
```

I just want to assign a variable :\

Comment: You cannot assign arrays. Consider using [`std::copy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy).

Comment: @MikeCAT you can't assign **C style** arrays. You *can* assign **C++ style** `std::array`s